# A list of the highest x's for each group

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a_list = [
'img_229_152_webp_1x', 
'img_229_152_webp_2x', 
'img_229_152_webp_3x', 
'img_229_152_webp_4x', 
'img_229_152_webp_5x', 
'img_246_164_webp_1x', 
'img_246_164_webp_2x', 
'img_246_164_webp_3x', 
'img_246_164_webp_4x']
```

Here we have two groups of images: `img_229_152_webp_5x'`, and `'img_246_164_webp_4x'`.

The list is sorted. And as for the last part (`\d+x`), each group of images is an   arithmetic progression, no missing element is possible. Example of impossible case: 1x, 2x, 4x.

Could you help me get a list of the highest x's for each group. In this case: `[img_229_152_webp_5x', 'img_246_164_webp_4x']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) you can group according to the prefix, and then get the max from each group:

```py
import itertools

for k, g in itertools.groupby(a_list, key=lambda s: s.rsplit('_', 1)[0]):
    print(max(g, key=lambda s: s.rsplit('_', 1)[-1]))
```

Gives:

```
img_229_152_webp_5x
img_246_164_webp_4x
```